# Changing the color of ggplotly when hovering over it in R Shiny App

Tags: r, shiny, ggplotly

I would like for the graphs in my shiny app to change color (or be highlighted) when I hover over them with my mouse. I would also like them to only output the count of my graph, instead of the count and the x-value.

Here is what it looks like in my Shiny App:
[image]

To be clear, I would like the bar that I am hovering over to turn light blue (or have a black outline) and to only say "count: 61735" without saying "fat_infreq(race): Black".

Below, I have attached a reproducible example:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(data.table)
library(shinythemes)
library(forcats)
require(stringi)
require(stringr)
library(scales)
library(ggthemes)
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggthemes)
library(forcats)
library(xtable)
library(googledrive)
library(googlesheets4)
library(gridExtra)
library(lubridate)
library(DT)
library(vroom)
library(utf8)
library(tableHTML)
library(bslib)
library(devtools)
library(readr)
library(RColorBrewer)

ethnicity <- c("Hispanic", "Non-hispanic","Hispanic","Hispanic","Hispanic","Hispanic","White","White","White","White", 
               "White","Hispanic","Hispanic", "Hispanic","Hispanic","Hispanic","White","White","White","White")
filtered_data <- data.frame(ethnicity)

ui <- fluidPage(

    
    titlePanel("Example"),
        mainPanel(
            plotlyOutput("ethnicity_barplot")
        )
    )

server <- function(input, output) {

    output$ethnicity_barplot <- renderPlotly({
        ggplotly({
            ethnicity_barplot <-ggplot(data = filtered_data, aes(x = fct_infreq(ethnicity))) + 
                geom_bar() + 
                xlab("Ethnicity") + 
                ylab("Number of People") + 
                labs(title = "Ethnicity of Defendants in New York State Courts") + 
                geom_bar(fill = "#327EC2") + 
                theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'white'))+
                theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = 'white'))+
                theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
                theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)) +
                geom_text(stat='count', aes(label=..count..), vjust = -.3)
            
            ethnicity_barplot
        })
    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

(Not all the packages are needed, just can't remember the ones that are)

Comment: Your code is not reproducible, please provide a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I have added a reproducible example